# Understanding difference between attr(x, "class") and class(x)

Tags: r, class, oop, primitive

## Background

I'm looking at the [jazz](https://github.com/romainfrancois/jazz) package proposed by Romain François. Romain defines a function `is_bare_vector` with the following syntax:

```
is_bare_vector <- function(x) {
  is_vector(x) && !is.object(x) && is.null(attr(x, "class"))
}
```

## Question

For: `x <- 1`:

```
attr(x, "class")
# NULL
```

Whereas:

```
class(x)
# [1] "numeric"
```

*I want to understand why those two functions provide different answers?* The help on `?attr` references `?class`

#### `?attr`

> Note that some attributes (namely `class`, `comment`, `dim`, `dimnames`,
>   `names`, `row.names` and `tsp`) are treated specially and have restrictions
>   on the values which can be set. (Note that this is not true of levels
>   which should be set for factors via the levels replacement function.)

#### `?class`

> Many R objects have a class attribute, a character vector giving the
>   names of the classes from which the object inherits. (Functions
>   `oldClass` and `oldClass<-` get and set the attribute, which can also be
>   done directly.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to read on a little further in `help("class")`:

> If the object does not have a class attribute, it has an implicit class, notably "matrix", "array", "function" or "numeric" or the result of typeof(x) (which is similar to mode(x))

Apparently `class()` will also return the implicit class if the class attribute is `NULL`; let's examine the [C source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/27da0eac8bb84677002febcf12e6d61bb7358d89/src/main/attrib.c#L625) -- 
we see that if the class attribute is of length 0, it gets the **implicit** class.:

```
SEXP R_data_class(SEXP obj, Rboolean singleString)
{
    SEXP value, klass = getAttrib(obj, R_ClassSymbol);
    int n = length(klass);
    if(n == 1 || (n > 0 && !singleString))
    return(klass);
    if(n == 0) {
    SEXP dim = getAttrib(obj, R_DimSymbol);
    int nd = length(dim);
    if(nd > 0) {
        if(nd == 2)
        klass = mkChar("matrix");
        else
        klass = mkChar("array");
    }
    else {
      SEXPTYPE t = TYPEOF(obj);
      switch(t) {
      case CLOSXP: case SPECIALSXP: case BUILTINSXP:
        klass = mkChar("function");
        break;
      case REALSXP:
        klass = mkChar("numeric");
        break;
      case SYMSXP:
        klass = mkChar("name");
        break;
      case LANGSXP:
        klass = lang2str(obj, t);
        break;
      default:
        klass = type2str(t);
      }
    }
    }
    else
    klass = asChar(klass);
    PROTECT(klass);
    value = ScalarString(klass);
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explanation, the *implicit class*, the source code is very useful.

Comment: @Konrad No problem! I've run into many things that mystify me in R until I look at the C source code. There's a lot of "under the hood" things that the documentation either will not explain or is kind of opaque about.